# Trying to create an array of vectors (Templatized Vector class created by me)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector, dynamic

So as the title mentions, I'm trying to create an array of vectors, vectors are not STL, I've made my own minimal class named Vector.h which is basically a dynamic array that can hold any type (templatized)

I'm reading in large amount of data from a file and seperating each line into meaningful attributes, which I am storing into the vector I made.

```
Vector<string> myDateVector;
Vector<string> myTimeVector;
Vector<float> mySolarRadiationVector;
Vector<float> myWindSpeedVector;
Vector<float> myAirTempVector;
```

Now I would like to make an array of these vectors, where each index of the array contains a pointer to the data in all of those vectors, as in array[1] has myDateVector.get(1); time(1) solarradiation(1) windspeed(1) airtemp(1).

Pretty lost on what to do now, very new to C++ and upon research STL vectors and things not related to my work are explained which makes me more confused, hence I found the need to post this. I really hope this isnt marked as duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly, you want to store all these vectors in one array.

For a few reasons, it's impossible. All elements of an array must have same type, while your vectors have different types.

If you really want to do this thing, you have two (or more, depends of your fantasy)  ways.

- Create tuple of vectors. Easiest variant, but you'd have to read article or two about tuples, if you pick it.
- Move `Vector<float>` to `Vector<std::string>`. Use `std::to_string`, Luke!  Then, just use `Vector<std::string> arr[5] = { /* here's your vectors of strings*/} ;`.

I have to apologize for my markup, because  mobile app is quite uncomfortable to use. So I do.

Comment: Is it not possible to templatize the array as well so it can accommodate all types of data?

Comment: @AashishPandav nope, because such array would not be array by definition and because of static typisation. Data structures that can contain different types are called "tuples", and are static too, with fixed size. Of course, dynamic tuples exist, but there is no dynamic tuples in STL.

Answer (score 0):

Write a container yourself

```
struct MyData
{
  std::tuple<string &, string &, float &, float &, float &> operator[](size_t row)
  {
    return std::tie(myDateVector[row], 
                    myTimeVector[row],
                    mySolarRadiationVector[row],
                    myWindSpeedVector[row],
                    myAirTempVector[row]);
  }

  string & operator()(size_t row, size_t col) 
  { 
    switch (col) 
    {
      case 0: return myDateVector[row];
      case 1: return myTimeVector[row];
    }
  }

  float & operator()(size_t row, size_t col)
  { 
    switch (col) 
    {
      case 2: return mySolarRadiationVector[row];
      case 3: return myWindSpeedVector[row];
      case 4: return myAirTempVector[row];
    }
  }

// and other useful members

private:
  Vector<string> myDateVector;
  Vector<string> myTimeVector;
  Vector<float> mySolarRadiationVector;
  Vector<float> myWindSpeedVector;
  Vector<float> myAirTempVector;
}
```